# How to pass arguments from subprocess.popen to powershell script?

Tags: python, windows, powershell, subprocess

I will need to get an argument from python script in the powershell script.

powershell code:

```
test.ps1
echo $args[0]
```

I am trying to call `test.ps1` using the below script.

Python code:

```
import subprocess, sys
import os

folder_path=os.getcwd()
p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe",
                      os.path.join(folder_path,"test.ps1"), "-arg1" , 5],
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
res=p.communicate()
```

I am getting the below error when I am executing the above script.

```
  needquote = (" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg) or not arg
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

I am sure I am missing something in the syntax, but couldn't figure it out.

SOlution:

```
import subprocess, sys
import os

folder_path=os.getcwd()
p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe",
                      os.path.join(folder_path,"test.ps1"), "-arg1" , "5"],
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
res=p.communicate()
```

5 should be in double quotes

Comment: `5` needs to be a string: `..."-arg1" , "5"] ...`